# How should I refactor the following situation so that Rails autoloads my class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Yesterday I posted this question with some strange autloading issue: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/83451042?noredirect=1

It seems that I kind of found the reason behind this, my actual code looks something like:\

a.rb

```
require_relative './b/b.rb'

module A

  def self.abc content
    return A::B.new
  end

end
```

B has nothing fancy:

b.rb

```
module A

  class B
    def initialize
    end
  end

  class C < B
    def initialize
      super
    end
  end
end
```

When I start my application, I can run `A::C` in console and find the class. After I `reload!`, `A::C` gives a `uninitialized constant`. When I then call `A::B` and shortly after `A::C` it works again.

So I guess I'm not able to have class C to reside in the same 'file' as B. Since C is closely related to B I thought it made sense to keep this comparable code together. Am I thinking wrongly here, or should I restructure this into something different?

Kind of new to working with classes outside the normal Rails stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I start my application, I can run A::C in console and find the
>   class. After I reload!, A::C gives a uninitialized constant. When I
>   then call A::B and shortly after A::C it works again.

Because `rails console` is not always as same as `reload!`. You can test this by configuring `cache_classes` to be `true` in `environments/development.rb`. You'll no longer get the error.

---

But you **should** follow the Rails's naming convention to **not** configure anymore, even `require_relative`. 
The final structure:

```
lib
-- my_lib
---- a
------ b.rb
------ c.rb
---- a.rb
```

Don't forget to add your lib `my_lib` to `autoload_paths`!

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to keep C closer related to B?

Comment: Like Rails controllers. If we create `UsersController` that is extended from `ApplicationController` (application_controller.rb).  We won't append `UsersController`  to the end of the file `application_controller.rb` but create a new one (users_controller.rb)

Comment: You can keep C in file `b.rb`, but It's hard to maintain. Eg: I want change something in class C but don't know where it is? (There is no file c.rb) or class B and class C will be bigger and bigger, it's better to keep theme seperated

Comment: And would it be an option to make C a subclass of B? In that case I can put the files in a separate folder /a/b/. Would be an elegant solution as well.

Comment: If you put c.rb in /a/b/, Rails will expect A::B::C, but your case is A::C. I’m not sure Rails can “autoload” properly